# Underlying connection was closed issue with C#.net and WordPress

Tags: c#, wordpress

I am trying to implement a functionality to post data on WordPress using C#.net.
I am following this example http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=419 but when I run code, it gives me following error.
The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

Please help me to find out what can be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually because XML RPC is disabled in your Wordpress install.

> To enable, go to Settings > Writing > Remote Publishing and check the checkbox
>   http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support

I'm the developer of an XML RPC wrapper called [JoeBlogs](http://github.com/alexjamesbrown/joeblogs) - I ran into this problem when developing it.